# Android - HorizontalScrollView: How can I scroll past views?

Tags: android, user-interface, horizontalscrollview

In my app I have a `HorizontalScrollView` that get `ImageButton`s added dynamically to it. I'd like to add some kind of margin to the right side of the scrollview or some way to "scroll past" for lack of a better word, the added items by ~100dp. I've tried adjusting margins and padding of the scrollview and its child layout to no avail.

I made a quick mockup that simulates what I want by using a blank `View` to push the scrollview farther out, which I guess would work, only it would be a pain to deal with.

As always I'm very grateful for any suggestions.

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel);
        LayoutParams params = ll.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 100;
    }

    public void addClicked(View view){
        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("Button");
        ll.addView(btn1, ll.getChildCount()-1);
    }

}
```

main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addClicked"
        android:text="Add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a right padding on the inner panel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="1000dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addClicked"
        android:text="Add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well. I coulda swore I did that, but copying your version directly works fine. So thank you and now i feel dumb.